# What's the minimum iOS version required to use the Facebook iOS SDK 3.1?

Tags: ios, facebook

The Facebook docs indicate that the new SDK supports new iOS 6 features, and is also backwards compatible to some degree. What's the minimum version of iOS that Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode project located in repository [specify iOS 3 as deployment target for SDK itself](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/e2b10bb2efbe6a176386092f2534e8beb4f1e885/src/facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj#L880) and iOS 5 for tests.

But probably you wouldn't be able to use it on iOS 3, see other question answered by Facebook employee: [Will Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 not work on iOS 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441067/will-facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-not-work-on-ios-3-x):

> Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 will not work with iOS 3.x. We felt that the productivity enhancements (e.g. blocks) in iOS 4.x were simply too useful. The SDK is open source, and we plan to maintain the history, which includes the existing code that does work with 3.x.