# facebook sdk for iOS 4.0

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

what version of facebook sdk should I get to make my app supported under iOS 4.0 ?I have xcode 4.5.

currently I have facebook sdk 3.1 and it I have tested from iOS 5.0 to 6. But the 4.0 version crashes while showing an error message that uses the FBSession class.

Comment: How many people even use iOS 4?  When I last looked at the numbers, the amount of people is nil.  Apple enthusiasts generally do a great job of staying with the times.

Comment: P.S. Xcode 4.5 can't compile for less than iOS 4.3

Comment: please see my update. If you want to ask the same question again please give a reason why you do that, because some people may down vote you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference link below, we can say that  `Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 Beta` support iOS 4.0 and later:

[Will Facebook iOS SDK 3.0 not work on iOS 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441067/will-facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-not-work-on-ios-3-x)

but for Facebook SDK 3.1 for iOS, from the below link:

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

, it says `Seamless Facebook Login across iOS versions: Lets your app work seamlessly on all iOS versions 4.3+ and easily integrates with the native login support in iOS 6`

hope it help you.

`Update`: 
reference from this link http://www.iphonehacks.com/2012/07/facebook-releases-sdk-3-0-for-ios.html

Improved Facebook APIs support:

Batching for SDK requests, which should significantly improve latency for Facebook API calls.

Facebook SDK 3.0 for iOS also includes support for iOS 6 that will be released later this fall:

After iOS 6 launches to users, the SDK will automatically use the native Facebook Login in iOS 6 when available. Just enable Login with Facebook and `the SDK will ensure your apps work seamlessly on all iOS versions 4.0 and later`. The SDK will continue to support the iOS 6 integration in beta until Apple’s user launch later this fall.